# convex polyhedron in the unit cube

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, algorithms, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, computational-geometry

Let $P$ be a given finite set of points within the $n$-dimensional unit cube. A finite set $Q$ of points within the $n$-dimensional unit cube *covers* $P$ if $\operatorname{conv}(Q) \supseteq P$ where $\operatorname{conv}(Q)$ denotes the convex hull of $Q$. How can one compute a minimal set $Q$ that covers $P$? Trivially, a minimal set $Q$ satisfies $|Q| \le |P|$ and $|Q| \le 2^n$. The minimal size could be computed by appealing to decision procedures for the first-order theory of the reals, but is there a smarter way?

Comment: Look at convex hull algorithms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms



Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a direct answer, but a closely related problem is known to be NP-hard:

> Das, Goodrich.
>   "On the Complexity of Approximating and Illuminating Three-Dimensional Convex Polyhedra."
>   1995. ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=645930.672852); [PDF download](http://ranger.uta.edu/~gdas/websitepages/preprints-papers/approx-illum.pdf))

This paper establishes several results, including this:

> **Theorem 4.2**. The problem of fitting a polyhedron with a minimum number of faces between 
>   two given nested convex polyhedra is NP-hard.

This question was first posed by Victor Klee, and I coauthored a paper that provided an
efficient algorithm in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But the above result shows it is already intractable
in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I do not remember the Das-Goodrich proof well enough to know if it can achieve the
same result with the outer polyhedron a cube.

There are many approximation algorithms available, as this is an important practical problem.
For example:

> Mitchell, Suri. "Separation and approximation of polyhedral surfaces."
>   In *Proc. 3rd ACM-SIAM Sympos. Discrete Algorithms*, pages 296-306, 1992. ([CiteSeer link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.160.2500))

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joseph. These pointers, especially the NP-hardness result, are extremely helpful.